# Python Prime Number for-else range

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, primes

```
lower = int(input("from:"))
upper = int(input("to:"))
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
```

Why does this code print "2" as a prime number? (it is but it should not print it)

**2%2==0 so it should skip it...**

Comment: What happens when `i` is 3?

Comment: `for i in range(2,num)` if num is 2 that's empy list so you wont get 2%2==0

Comment: Well.... two is a prime number.  It can only be divided by itself and one.  However, I do see the error in your code causing the unexpected response:  `range(start,end)` needs the `end` to be greater than the `start`.  Python's duck-typing means a check won't be performed and your if statment doesn't get checked.  I wish python didn't do that, but unfortunately it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `num` is 2, `range(2, num)` is empty, so the `if (num % i) == 0:` check is not performed, and the `else` block executes.

Answer (score 1):

Others have noted the error in the `range(start,end)` code.  Correcting that, your code for primes could be rewritten as:

```
lower = int(input("from:"))
upper = int(input("to:"))
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,max(num,3)):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
```

This isn't the fastest way to get primes mind you, each potential prime must be tested against EVERY smaller number as a possible divisor.  It's much faster to instead count upwards and work out the multiples of smaller numbers.  That way we only need to do the maths once for each possible divisor.

For completeness, here is a program that can produce primes efficiently (uses the sieve of Eratosthenes method).

```
#### INPUTS    
lower = int(input("from:"))
upper = int(input("to:"))

### Code
n = upper
prime_booleans = [True for i in range(n+1)] 
p = 2
while (p * p <= n): 

    # Is current number a prime, eliminate the numbers that are multiples of it 
    if (prime_booleans[p] == True): 
        for i in range(p * 2, n+1, p): 
            prime_booleans[i] = False
    p += 1

# Print all prime numbers 
for p in range(lower, n): 
    if prime_booleans[p]: 
        print p,
```